# How to encrypt and decrypt a dart file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to encrypt and decrypt a whole dart file in flutter ?

Thanks in advance,
Ashwin

Comment: Hi ashwin, please add some relevant research work of yours regarding the question like where you are confused or what have you tried  ?

Comment: Hi ! Can you be more specific ? What kind of cypher do you want to use ? Why would you want to encrypt a **dart** file ?

Comment: I need to upload my whole project in a public forum, but i should not want the end users to copy my source code. Can you please suggest me a way to encrypt my dart files. I am not familiar with cyphers.

Answer (score 0):

flutter encrypy link :

flutter have encrypt / decrypt algorithm

https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt a whole dart file using encrypt package?

Comment: whole dart file using encrypt is impossible